# migrate content from Sharepoint intranet to Sitecore

Tags: sharepoint, migration, sitecore

There are many paid tools available to migrate content from Sharepoint to Sitecore like Kapow, Siteport etc. Are there any open source tools available to migrate content from Sharepoint intranet to Sitecore?

Answer (score 0):

There is an integration services marketplace module that does data transformation, but not specific to Sharepoint. I haven't tried to use it to query for data from Sharepoint, but it is shared source so you can probably make it do what you need.

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/I/Integration_Services_Components_for_Sitecore.aspx?sc_lang=en